# How to get Gnuplot not to crop scientific notation

Tags: resize, gnuplot, crop

I'm using gnuplot to generate the following surface plot.

[image: Gnuplot cropped z-axis]

The important part of the command file I'm using is:

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 3,3;
```

In particular the `size 3,3` resizes the plot to the way I want but crops out part of the z-axis label in the process. If I use a wider size like `size 4,3` or don't use the size option at all then the z-axis labels fit as follows:

[image]

It seems that gnuplot doesn't take the width of the label into consideration when resizing the plot.

Is there a way to maybe move the plot to the right before resizing to `3,3` so that there's room to scientific notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `lmargin` option:

```
set lmargin 10
```

(or whatever size doesn't crop the label).